# Detect if-else output PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to make a PowerShell string to compile a program and if it's correctly compiled, I want to open the the program. The problem that I'm trying to solve is to understand how PowerShell understands when the [MiniGW](http://mingw.org/) compiler with `gcc` command (for C files) throws a correct result.

Knowing that `== TRUE` and `== FALSE` are not accepted in PowerShell I tried an `if` without any logical operator

```
if(gcc '.\FileINeedToCompile.c'){
  Write-Host Correct;
} else {
  Write-Host NotCorrect;
}
```

but I get the `NotCorrect` result in the case that the program is correctly compiled and also the case it's not compiled.

I've also tried some varietions with the logical operator `-eq` like

`if((gcc '.\FileINeedToCompile.c') -eq $FALSE)`

but I get always the result of the `else` statement.

I searched everywhere and I really don't know how I could make this working.
Thanks for help.

Comment: What does `gcc` return on a successful compilation?

Comment: What's returned by `gcc '.\FileINeedToCompile.c'`? You can check the object type with `(gcc '.\FileINeedToCompile.c').getType()`. I would speculate that it is a string, so try `if((gcc '.\FileINeedToCompile.c') -eq "False")`

Comment: I suggest you look into [using `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) instead of trying to roll your own build system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the gcc and capture the error code for processing. I didn't test with gcc, but I did test with a small console app and this works assuming a return code of 0 is success.

```
gcc '.\FileINeedToCompile.c'
if($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0){
  Write-Host Correct;
} else {
  Write-Host NotCorrect;
}
```

A bit more info on this can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/09/15/errorlevel-equivalent/).